Find the radius of convergence using Cauchy-Hadaman formula or termwise differentiation/integration
Find the radius of convergence of the series
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n}{5^n} (z+2i)^{2n}$$
using both the Cauchy-Hadamard formula and piecewise differentiation or integration.
The first part is quite straightforward.
$$\begin{split} R = \frac{1}{L^*} &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left|\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\right| \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n/5^n}{(n+1)/5^{n+1}}\\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n}{5^n}\cdot\frac{5^{n+1}}{n+1}\\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{5}{1+(1/n)}=5 \end{split}$$
However, I struggle doing the piecewise differentiation or integration. The series has so many n terms both the integral and differential seem quite complex. Looking at the result of it on WolframAlpha gives results far off any series I may know.
Any idea how this might be solved?

You do not actually say what $a_n$ is. Usually we take $a_n$ to mean the coefficient of $(z-z_0)^n$ is the series. That is not what you use, as in this series $a_n/a_{n+1}$ is often undefined.

I understood that a power series generally is $\Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty} a^n z^n$, such that $\frac{n}{5^n}$ becomes $a_n$ here. Is this incorrect?

Notice how $z + 2i$ is put to the power $2n$ and not $n$, thus every $a_{2n+1}$ is $0$, while $a_{2n}$ is $n 5^{-n}$. In this case you'd rather want to use the Hadamard formula $R^{-1} = \limsup_{n \to \infty} |a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}$, as this way it will be well-defined.

$$S=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n}{5^n} (z+2i)^{2n}$$
$$\frac {(z+2i)^2}5=t \quad \implies \quad S=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n,t^n=\frac{t}{(t-1)^2}$$ could help

Thank you guys, so I have now figured out it looks like a differenciated power series and found its ROC to be $|t| \leq 1$, which implies that $|z+2i| < \sqrt{5}$ which implies the ROC is $\sqrt{5}$. However, this means my solution using Cauchy-Hadamard is wrong. I can unfortunately not use the other variation of the formula, and I don't see which term of $nt^n$ would be $a_n$ in this case.
